# Making Global Variables Locally

Tags: vb.net, scope

In VB.Net can you declare variables locally (in a method) and have them have a global scope?

I'm new-ish to VB.Net and am trying to figure out some of the ways the language works.  In a previous project I did with C++ I was able to inside of a method declare a variable as global, saving memory space until the first time that method was called and the variable was instantiated.

Just curious if this is something that is possible with VB.Net.

Comment: quite honestly the last thing you should worry about when programming in .NET is saving a few bytes. Consider this: the computer you are likely to run the app on will have between 4 and 16gb of ram. the bottlenecks of any app you write are going to be disk access, network speed, db engine processing or any other number of things slower than allocating memory in RAM.

Comment: The `Public` modifier does not "lift" a variable out of its scope.  It simply adjusts "who" is allowed to access it.  Additionally, `Public` is not valid inside a method.

Comment: @Jeremy: On a windows box, yes, but what about .NET on resource-constrained devices, like a Raspberry Pi, or Netduino, or cheap web host VM?  (I know, Netduino is C#, not VB, but who knows in the future).  Programming with resources in mind is not a bad practice.

Comment: Do you mean global scope or global storage duration?

Comment: @RaymondChen honestly, I am interested in knowing if both are possible.  If only one is, or both are, or none are, I'm able to apply the knowledge to how I am programming this.

Comment: What kind of variable are you talking about? A class in VB.NET takes no data space, only an instance of the class does.

Comment: A variable declared in a method as `Static` will retain its value between calls to the method but is not visible outside the method.

Comment: What was the C++ technique for "I was able to inside of a method declare a variable as global, saving memory space until the first time that method was called and the variable was instantiated."? Function-local statics do not save memory space, and they are not visible globally.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation in .NET can make it difficult to implement a global variable in the way you are thinking of one. The closest solution may be to declare a public variable in a module, but it isn't immediately available inside another module.

The way I usually do what you're thinking is to create a singleton class "globals" that contains member fields representing the global variables I want to move around, then I just pass my "globals" instance as an argument.

```
Public Dim myGlobals as GlobalClass
myGlobals.someVariable = "preserve me"
```

Then making them available to be accessed by the method: `someMethod(myGlobals)` will pass them by reference by default.

Answer (score 0):

So Jacob posted an pretty good answer to my question.  After a bit more researching, I think my best bet is to do something similar to the following:

```
Class ScopeTest

    Private randVar As Object = Nothing

    Sub Initialize()
        randVar = New Label()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Essentially, create the variable at the highest level scope I need it, and set it to `Nothing` so that no data (should be) allocated to it, but the variable name has the appropriate scope.  Then I just instantiate the variable whenever I call it the first time, and then it will be implemented throughout the rest of the code.

Obviously the largest pitfall with this setup is if I go to call the object while it is equal to `Nothing`.  This will require me to add in some `If Not IsNothing` statements to the code, but since I can't seem to find a better way to go about this, it's what I will be doing at the moment.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you can implement it as a property, and have the check to do first initilization in the property get, then your code is not littered with checks of Nothing. It does seem to me that you are going through gyrations for arguably minimal benefit. Isn't a Label a UI element, or is it a custom class of yours?

Comment: In your example randVar is private, so it would not be accessible when ScopeTest is instantiated. Recommend using public.

Comment: @Jeremy I was using Label as an example

Comment: You can use [a shared constructor](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25742&seqNum=8) to initialize on first use of the class, or you can use [a local static](https://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/7717) to initialize on first use of a method, or you can use [a `Lazy(of T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization) to initialize on first use of the variable.